# How to hint font dejavu sans mono on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, xterm, fontconfig

The default DejaVu Sans Mono font in OpenBSD **xterm** looks too fat.  Settings in ~/.Xdefaults are:

```
xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
xterm*faceSize: 12
```

How to hint this font on **OpenBSD** (e.g. by changes in /etc/fonts)?